# Docker tab/command completion not showing all commands

Tags: docker, oh-my-zsh, tab-completion

User A on my macOS with oh-my-zsh installed and docker zsh plugin enabled sees this when I do tab completion:

```
 $ docker i<tab>
image    -- Manage images
images   -- List images
import   -- Import the contents from a tarball to create a filesystem image
info     -- Display system-wide information
init     -- Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc., v0.1.0-beta.4)
inspect  -- Return low-level information on Docker objects
```

I'm setting up User B on the same machine also using oh-my-zsh but instead of the nice completion above, when I do `docker i<tab>` it results in `docker inspect`. None of the other options show up. Same with `docker p<tab>` which just shows the options for `ps` and `prune` but none of the other subcommands which begin with the letter `p` like `pause`, `pull`, `port`, etc. I also don't see the subcommand descriptions like with User A. User B just sees the command without a description.

Both machines are running the same version of zsh.

What might explain why docker completion works so differently for User B compared to User A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's because of Docker plugin update. Long story short, add the following line to your `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':omz:plugins:docker' legacy-completion yes
```

(as described in the plugin's [README](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/docker#use-old-style-completion))

You can find details here: [Completion is not working properly with Docker version 24.0.2](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/11789). Waiting for a fix from the Docker team. After that, you can remove this setting from the config.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like User A has an older version of the oh-my-zsh docker plugin while User B has a newer version. I think the new version is probably buggy.